# Show/hide menu link based on changing custom $tempStore value

Tags: 8, routes, navigation, caching

I'd like to show/hide a main-menu link based on a `$tempStore` variable the user can set and modify during their session, i.e.

- user sets `$tempStore['vlaue'] = 0;` --> menu link is hidden
- user sets `$tempStore['value'] = 1;` --> menu link is shown.

The menu link is provided by a view (page). What I started to do is to implement my own custom `RouteSubscriber` which adds a custom access check  (which is defined as a service in `mymodule.service.yml`) to the view. The custom access check in `myCustomAccessCheck.php` basically does the following

```
   ...
   $value = $tempstore->get('value');
   return AccessResultAllowed::allowedIf($value == 1);
   ...
```

Apparently Drupal by default hides all menu links that the user does not have access to, so this approach should work (which it actually does!). However, caching is a problem, i.e. when the user changes the value, the link is shown/hidden only after a `cache-rebuild`.

Now my question:

- Is there a better/more elegant approach to do this? (I could not find any)
- If not, can I use some hook to add my custom cache tag to the menu-link? (the view itself already has this cache tag, but the provided menu link does not respond to it)
- Is it "better" to make a view-block instead of view-page, using a hook to add the custom cache tag to the block and add the block to the menu via *.links.menu.yml to have more control over the behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to add the custom cache tag to the access result:

```
return AccessResult::allowed()->addCacheTags(['custom_cache_tag']);
return AccessResult::forbidden()->addCacheTags(['custom_cache_tag']);
```